# How to build Google python API for cloud endpoint server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I have my Google app engine project which has Cloud endpoints hosted. I would wish to make API calls to my Cloud endpoints using python client library.

It can easily achieved when the library is a Google library:
Example:

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
service = build('compute', 'v1', http=http).instances()
response = service.insert(project=project_id, zone=zone, body=body).execute()
```

I wish to know if same library can be utilized to make API calls my custom endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `discoveryServiceUrl='https://foo.appspot.com/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis/{api}/{apiVersion}/rest'` to your `build` method call. See the [official documentation](http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/googleapiclient.discovery-module.html#build).

However, you might want to use [apitools](https://github.com/google/apitools) instead.